# nth-child style not applied

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

So, I have bumped into the following problem. I'm trying to give the "heading" all a different color using `nth-child`.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<header>
    <h1>Title<br />
    <span>Subtitle</span></h1>

    <p><strong>Heading</strong><br />
    text</p>
    <p><strong>Heading</strong><br />
    text</p>
    <p><strong>Heading</strong><br />
    text</p>
</header>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
header h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: .65em;
}
header h1 span {
    font-size: .5em;
}
header p {
    font-size: .9em;
}
header p strong {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
header p:nth-child(1) strong { color: #f3b200; }
header p:nth-child(2) strong { color: #d27b26; }
header p:nth-child(3) strong { color: #dc572e; }
```

Without the `<h1>`, it works perfectly, check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LRWXd/2/).

But with the `<h1>`, it seems to see the `<h1>` as a `<p>`. Making the last "heading" not having a color. Check the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LRWXd/1/).

I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: There is no `<p>` which is the 4th child. You probably want `nth-of-type`.

Comment: nth-child actually does elements in the parent container - it doesn't take into account the selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because if [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) didn't found the `nth` number of element matching `p` element, so it will fail, use [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type) instead

```
header p:nth-of-type(1) strong { color: #f3b200; }
header p:nth-of-type(2) strong { color: #d27b26; }
header p:nth-of-type(3) strong { color: #dc572e; }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LRWXd/3/)

Comment: Ah, it can be so easy sometimes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By adding another element (the `<h1>`) the indices you use in the selectors are now **off by 1**. You might have noticed that the heading colours in your second demo have shifted up by one position also.

You could just increase the indices on the original CSS to select the new positions

```
header p:nth-child(2) strong { color: #f3b200; }
header p:nth-child(3) strong { color: #d27b26; }
header p:nth-child(4) strong { color: #dc572e; }
```

but the better solution is to use a different CSS selector [`nth-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo) pseudo-class which takes the actual element into consideration, as already shown in Mr. Alien's answer.